# How to use CSS3 text-decoration-skip?

Tags: css, typography, text-decorations

In CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3, there’s [`text-decoration-skip`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#propdef-text-decoration-skip). It does magic like this:
[image: The word “parapsychology” underlined with descenders skipped.]
This representation is allegedly produced by using `text-decoration-skip: ink;`. For web typography, it’d be great if descenders are no longer struck through by native underlining.

There’s an entry at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/) and more recently also one on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip). There, it says it’s “not on a standards track”. Is that right? The property is listed in the [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-skip).

How can I use `text-decoration-skip`? Or *when*? Are there flags to enable it?

Comment: I think no one can answer when can you start to use this.

Comment: Regarding *when*, I hope for browser developers or community contributors. Concerning *how*, I assumed somebody might have found a way to use it, even if it was, for instance, an experimental browser or a polyfill or anything tangible.

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the comments to the question, there's no saying when and how it will be implemented.

For reference anmd clarification, [the origin article of the picture you posted](https://medium.com/design/crafting-link-underlines-on-medium-7c03a9274f9) isn't what the actual spec necessarily will look like, but a draft of what Marcin Wichary had in mind when tinkering with it. So don't make the mistake and consider that image a reference for the CSS3 output, as it may look entirely different when finally implemented.

I also can't tell you why MDN doesn't list it as a feature necessarily to be implemented, whether it's a decision of the development team not to implement it, or they just missed it. I can, however, tell you that they are correct in saying *"This property has not yet been implemented in any modern browser."*

---

As for browser support, take note of [this comment](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-skip/#comment-1595245) in the CSS-Tricks article, linking to the folliowing image:

[image: Netscape 3.7.7]

It's not only interesting because that's quite a dated browser (which of course didn't do this because of some CSS3 spec, but likely because they had the same basic idea), but also because that's likely what the property will look like when finally implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your assessment. I probably should emphasize the *“allegedly”* in the OP, because I never said the image showed actual output. Even if it was implemented, there *definitely* will be rendering variances across browsers. Netscape 3 however is a really nice discovery. **iOS** does this automatically as well for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

While `text-decoration-skip` seems to have been *“[deferred](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#changes-2013) to Level 4 to allow for major changes”*, Chrome 64 (2018-01) and Firefox 70 (2019-10) implemented a close relative (applied by default), because *“most other browsers are converging on supporting the simpler [`text-decoration-skip-ink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink) property”*, and it certainly does work:

```css
u{font-size:444%;}
u:first-of-type{ text-decoration-skip-ink: none; }
u:last-of-type{ text-decoration-skip-ink: auto; }
```

```html
<u>parapsychologists</u>
<br>
<u>parapsychologists</u>
```

Note that there’s even more cutting-edge text-decoration stuff, like [`text-underline-offset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset) or [`text-decoration-thickness`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness).